# How to get timeline posts details from Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook login/Like/Comment/Share features.
I refer the following link to login with FB
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

But unfortunately i dont have any samples for getting the Facebook page timeline post details with the valid access token which is returned from successful login.
Please give me the solutions

Comment: Really looking forward the great solutions

Answer (score 0):

you can check everything with the help of [Android Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) you can see how to share a particular `timeline link` or `whatever link in facebook` and just connect it into android.

I hope these may be helpful to you.